Why am I getting weird cannot be applied to warnings in build.gradle
I am trying to create a task to handle Node project files. I currently have the following....
tasks.register('buildUi', Exec) { task ->
    task.workingDir = uiProjectDir
    task.inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/src")
    task.inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/node_modules")
    task.outputs.dir(uiDistDir)
    task.dependsOn tasks.named('npmInstall')

    // Use bash directly when in WSL
    task.commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'npm run build'
}

I see two warnings first is on the first line

'register' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec>, groovy.lang.Closure)'

The second is on task.dependsOn tasks.named('npmInstall')

'named' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

If I ask CoPilot it just goes back and forth between
task.dependsOn tasks.getByName('npmInstall') and tasks.register('buildUi', Exec).configure { task ->
But they all seem to have the same warning. What is the proper way to do this to avoid the warnings?
Update
This was another suggestion....
tasks.register('buildUi', Exec) {
    workingDir = uiProjectDir
    inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/src")
    inputs.dir("${uiProjectDir}/node_modules")
    outputs.dir(uiDistDir)
    dependsOn tasks.named('npmInstall')

    // Use bash directly when in WSL
    commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'npm run build'
}

Which is the functional equivalent without the lambda expression. However, the warnings still persist...

'register' cannot be applied to '(java. lang. String, java. lang. Class<org. gradle. api. tasks. Exec>, groovy. lang. Closure)'


'named' cannot be applied to '(java. lang. String)'


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:    2024-09-23 21:28:39 UTC
Revision:      415adb9e06a516c44b391edff552fd42139443f7

Kotlin:        1.9.24
Groovy:        3.0.22
Ant:           Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
Launcher JVM:  23 (Oracle Corporation 23+37-2369)
Daemon JVM:    /home/jgleason/lib/java/jdk-23 (no JDK specified, using current Java home)
OS:            Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 amd64


I'm not well versed in Gradle's Groovy DSL (or Groovy itself for that matter), but if I'm not mistaken that task -> part is not supposed to be there. And it should just be, e.g., workingDir = ... instead of task.workingDir = .... The task object is held in an implicit "this". Or at least, that's how it works in Kotlin (i.e., the Kotlin DSL).

Yes, @Slaw has it. Here is some explanation from Gradle

I understand there are 2 ways to do it my point is they both don't work I will explain more in the question

Didn't know Groovy lets you name the delegate in a closure. In Kotlin, trying to name the receiver in a lambda would result in a compiler error (i.e., the task -> would fail to compile in the Kotlin DSL). That said, I'm not seeing the warnings in Gradle 8.11. Which version of Gradle are you using? Is there a more complete [mre] that would better demonstrate the problem?

Added more examples the reproducible sample should be available here
https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-ai-example

I cloned your repo and opened it in IntelliJ 2024.3 CE. I only get the "vulnerable dependency" and the "useJUnitJupiter cannot be applied to String" warnings. Everything regarding the tasks, even if I change the dependsOn calls to use tasks.named, gives no warnings. Of course, the useJUnitJupiter shouldn't be giving that warning, so something is still going wrong. But the JUnit Jupiter dependencies are still added correctly. If the build still works then you can probably just ignore the warnings, since therefore it seems to be a bug with IntelliJ, not Gradle or your build script.

Ok I will try out those suggestions when I get back thank you. And I figured it is just IJ being picky but since I couldn't understand why it was being picky I wanted to make sure it was a hallucination
